# Do not lint node_modules

Tags: scripting, eslint, package.json, lint

In my package.json in scripts i have a field

```
"lint": "tsc --noEmit && eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx ./"
```

Before commit i'm using Husky, that lint my project

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged && yarn lint"
    }
  },
```

And for some reasons i have a problem in my console

```
$ tsc --noEmit && eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx ./
node_modules/react-navigation-header-buttons/index.d.ts:111:14 - error TS7051: Parameter has a name but no type. Did you mean 'arg0: OnOverflowMenuPressParams'?

111   onPress?: (OnOverflowMenuPressParams) => any;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Found 1 error.

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

As i see, problem with some types in node_modules. I add them to my .eslintinnore, but continue getting the same error. I try to exclude .ts from there byt error stay the same

```
"lint": "tsc --noEmit && eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.tsx ./"
```

How can i stop checking types in node_modules?
I can fix this adding any in node_modules/react-navigation-header-buttons/index.d.ts :

```
onPress?: (OnOverflowMenuPressParams: any) => any;
```

in but i'm tired doing it every time.

Maybe anyone have better suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's just about bumping the typescript version in your dev dependencies.

Check the typescript version in the `package.json` of the library that is complaining, in this case it would be `node_modules/react-navigation-header-buttons/package.json`. Perhaps the version is higher than the one in your project.

Comment: underrated answer right here

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this with fixing node_modules with adding arg0:

```
 onPress?: (arg0: OnOverflowMenuPressParams) => any;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an .eslintignore file to your project with node_modules in it

Comment: it`s not working for me, as a removing .ts from 'lint' string or adding node_modules exception to it. I still have no idea why.